# How to rename multiple files from the multiple text files?

Tags: batch-rename

My goal is to do following:

I am using Win 10 and I have files like so:

```
folder
   2020-04-23_19-30-52_UTC.mp4
   2020-04-23_19-30-52_UTC.txt which contains string "This video is me at a wedding"
   2020-05-25_19-30-52_UTC.mp4
   2020-05-25_19-30-52_UTC.txt which contains string "This video is dogwalk at the sunset"
```

where .txt contains the name of the mp4 from the same date and I want to do the following:

```
  folder
    This video is me at a wedding.mp4
    2020-04-23_19-30-52_UTC.txt
    This video is dogwalk at the sunset.mp4
    2020-05-25_19-30-52_UTC.txt
```

there is a few ways how to achieve this but I am not that good with coding. My only priority is to have it done and I am for now not limited to use of any tool or programming language.

Thanks

Comment: OK, so you mean that each text file contains the name you want to give the corresponding .mp4 file, and nothing else?  Also, are there any restrictions on the tools that can be used?  Is this Windows?

Comment: @Spencer yes, the txt contains just the name but that name is sometimes like 3 sentences long but I personally don't mind. Sorry for not adding this, I have edited the post and accidentally removed the part that said this is Win 10. Also no restrictions on the tools of any kind, I just need it done. Thanks and sorry

Comment: Please edit that back in to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tackle this problem with Python.

```
import os

dir = ('[path to original folder]')

files = os.listdir(dir)

# Iterate through all the files in the folder
for path in files:
     
     filetype = path[-4:] # Grabs last 4 characters of the filepath
     
     # Checks if it's a textfile
     if (filetype == '.txt'):

          f = open(os.path.join(dir, path), "r") # open the textfile
          
          new_name = f.read() # grab the description

          f.close() # close the textfile

          new_name = new_name + '.mp4' # Add proper filetype

          path = path[:-4] # Throws away the last 4 characters of the filepath

          path = path + '.mp4' # Add proper filetype

          os.rename(os.path.join(dir, path), os.path.join(dir, new_name)) # Rename
```

If any more issues arise please let me know so I can help.

Comment: Thanks but I have 600 files which I need to change so this would take like forever to execute, no?

Comment: Edited my solution so it can be scaled up. Does this help?

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly should the path to the original folder look like? Because when I run it I get "OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: " and I tried both types of slashes and everything else and I moved files up and down to simplifiy the path but I still got the error. But yeah, this is exactly what I wanted. Sorry for unconvinience

Comment: My code was buggy, I changed the way it handled filepaths. Does it work now?

Comment: An example line for the directory: dir = (r'C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Desktop')

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kat.py", line 5, in <module>
    files = os.listdir(dir)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '[C:\\original]' 

I have moved the folder straight to the C and I am running it via powershell and no matter what I do it still have this problem

Comment: Get rid of the brackets. Try  dir = r'C:\\original', dir = 'C:\\original', and single backslash variants of those two. Alternatively, copy the filepath directly. [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/670447/how-to-copy-the-full-path-of-a-file-on-windows-10/)